# Is it appropriate to vote to reopen specific duplicates with broad targets when new answers depend on a yet unreleased feature?

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-reopen

This question is about Go because that's the tag I watch, but it can be easily extended to any technology.

---

Go is about to release version 1.18 which will bring generics to the language. This is a **major** new feature which will warrant [new answers to old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer). The very existence of the Necromancer badge seems encouraging new answers to old questions.

It's perhaps reasonable to expect that some questions will be simply re-asked now that they can be framed more appropriately with generics in mind.

Some other questions though **don't have to** be re-asked, especially those that already exist on Stack Overflow and are already enough of [clear | well-written | general] that they can simply benefit from a new Go 1.18 answer.

When those questions are already open, one can simply go ahead and add a new answer (which I often do).

In some cases those questions are closed, and most egregiously, closed as duplicates of some broad Q&A that explains why Go has no generics. Then the only reasonable course of action IMO is to vote to reopen. One blatant example is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646378/how-do-you-implement-a-container-for-different-types-in-go). (There are others which I won't link since contain answers that I authored).

In the linked example, a specific question about how to implement a generic container in Go is closed as dupe of something that broadly asks/explains why Go doesn't have generics.

This dupe target may have been (sort of) appropriate back in 2017 when Go had no generics in sight. The dupe is now invalid, as Go is about to release 1.18 with generics.

However the linked question, and the other ones I have in mind, **do not** pass scrutiny and stay closed ([review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30620585)), with the reason:

> Original close reason(s) were not resolved

Well, considering that:

- Go 1.18 is [already released in beta](https://go.dev/blog/go1.18beta1)
- Answers that reference the Go generics proposal, but also other new features that are included with this release, are being provided since 2020, well before Go 1.18 was even in active development<sup>1</sup>.

I believe that the original close reasons are indeed resolved.

**It is still true** that Go 1.18 isn't officially out, and you could argue (although it'd be a weak argument) that unreleased features may change, and thus invalidate existing answers<sup>2</sup>.

I don't know if this is what causes those questions to stay closed, or if simply the reviewers believe it's not yet time to reopen for some other reason.

**QUESTION: what is the appropriate course of action when a specific  question is closed as a dupe of a broader one and can have new specific answers based on an unreleased feature?**

---

<sup>1: BTW, this latter point is true also for other earlier Go versions. Answers will simply come when people have the reasonable certainty that some feature will be *eventually* added. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69656800) is dated October 2021. VonC in particular frequently adds answers as soon as he sees the changelist in the Go source.</sup>

<sup>2: though that's maybe the answerer's problem</sup>

Comment: While it won't change what to do in the long run, I feel there is no rush to act *right now* before the feature is actually released. You might just as well wait to act until it is a released feature, which would remove at least some of the complications of the situation.

Comment: I feel like having a clean Q/A handling generics in GO would be better than reopening old questions. Then you have a useful dupe target for new and those old questions to link to.

Comment: @yivi Apples and oranges? Closing as dupe means “this question has answers there”. In this case, the upcoming release is going to completely invalidate the current dupe target. If I were an unregistered user and clicked on some link to that question and got automatically redirected to that dupe target I would find it very weird and confusing. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 moreover if I had a gold badge I could just go ahead and reopen. So based on what you say, would that be an incorrect action? Would I be abusing the gold badge privilege?

Comment: @yivi *If the question was closed as a dupe, it's either a dupe and should remain closed, or it's not* — I don't know, is "[tech] doesn't have X" a valid dupe target for "how do I do Y in [tech] that implies the existence of X"? If you take it at face value, maybe it is, because an answer to that question necessarily includes explaining that [tech] does indeed not have X. Then X gets added to [tech] and the dupe becomes invalid.

Comment: @Tom I generally agree, many possible questions involving generics do benefit from their own Q&A, though in *some* cases, e.g. the question I linked, the issue at hand is already framed with this upcoming feature in mind, so if you were to re-ask it today, you would basically copy the title over

Comment: *"you would basically copy the title over"* ... maybe, depending on how you frame the new Q/A. But reopening the old question would keep the old and outdated answers and comments there and I don't see how that would be helpful. That's why I wrote a "clean Q/A" would be more useful, I assume.

Comment: *"The dupe is now invalid, as Go is about to release 1.18 with generics."* Not at all, the dupe is completely valid, and hopefully someone (if not you can) post a new answer that starts with something like "In Version 1.18 Generics were added to the GO Language; {link to release announcement}. To implement these you... {Descriptive answer with links to documentation}." Now, when people visit the dupe they can see that *if* they update their version, they have access to the technology *and* if they get to a question that was previously closed as a dupe, they get to find it too, Win win!

Comment: I feel I'm having a hard time getting my point across. Maybe I should just post an answer on the dupe target and call it a day...

Comment: *"Maybe I should just post an answer on the dupe target and call it a day."* that would be the normal thing to do.

Comment: @Larnu Q:"why go doesn't have generics", A: "the way to implement containers in Go is doing X, Y and creating a generic". I don't want that to be a normal thing to do.

Comment: I didn't say use my exact words, @Braiam and take them out of context. The answer to that would be "It does, in Version 1.18..." that would be the sensible answer...

Comment: @Larnu but that's exactly what you are telling the user to do, so I don't take them out of context, I bought them to context and pointed out how ridiculous it is. There's no way your advice isn't ridiculous in any context.

Comment: @yivi well, [there you go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21196132/792066) (pun inteded)

Comment: No, @Braiam ... If the answer to a question changes then post a new answer. I don't know why you're against that... Posting lots of the "same" question doesn't help the community...

Comment: @Larnu You aren't reading: they are *different questions*. How to do X isn't the same to why language doesn't have feature Y.

Comment: Same question, different ways of asking, @Braiam . Especially when the answer to the question "Why go doesn't have generics" is now "It does from version 1.18, here's how", and thus a question asking "How do I implement generics in Go" with an answer of "here's how you do" will be a great duplicate candidate. Or vice versa, of course.

Comment: @Larnu your argument is the literal definition of cart before horse, you don't ask questions thinking about the answers, you ask questions thinking about the problem. Stop doing that. I blame Jeff "rule of thumb" for that abomination. Duplicate questions are questions that semanticall ask the same thing. How and why are totally different semantic constructions from the ground up.

Comment: Perhaps it is you that isn't reading, @Braiam . I've said my part, if you post your answer, I'll be happy to vote on it.

Answer (score 4):

> When those questions are closed, and most egregiously, closed as duplicates of something that explains why Go has no generics, the only reasonable course of action IMO is to vote to reopen.

The question remains the same, so it's still a duplicate, but the answer changed, so the dupe target becomes outdated...

Just answer the dupe target with an answer explaining how it works in the new version.

Comment: it's weird to answer "Why does X not have Y" or similar generically framed questions with an example of how to accomplish some **specific** task with Y. Then every possible variation of specific questions that involve this new feature Y could potentially be closed as dupe, and over time "Why does X not have Y" would contain answers to all sort of **specific** tasks that can be accomplished with Y. This is what this answer implies. It's the opposite of "discoverability" and "specificity". The specific questions should be just reasked, but what if they already exist on the site...

Comment: There's no need to have 5 versions of the same question for 5 different versions, @blackgreen , that doesn't help your "discoverability" at all. *One* question with all the answers, detailing what version they are applicable, and duplicates pointing to that one answer is by far the better method; you discover one question with all the answers. Finding an answer that doesn't work for you, as you use an old version, to search, find another answer that doesn't work for the same reason, to search and finally find one that does isn't good UX when they could have all been in one place.

Comment: This answer is fundamentally wrong. The questions are not the same: one asks "how to do X", the other asks "why language doesn't have Y". Those are separated questions. The correct answer to the first question should have been "sadly you can't do that since the language doesn't have feature Y, see this other question for the why". The questions are related at best, but not duplicates.

Comment: Then they shouldn't have been closed as dupes in the first place, @Braiam. Correctly closed duplicates don't suddenly become non-duplicates just because a language feature is added.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in cases where the premises built into your question are actually true. Namely, there is a new change or upcoming change, and either

1. the questions were never truly duplicates of each other, and the change is just making that easier to see, or
2. the questions were arguably duplicates in the past because at the time they warranted the same answers, but due to the change they warrant different answers.

Ultimately, *the duplicate target should actually answer the marked-as-duplicate question*.

If you can best achieve that by contributing a new or edited answer on the duplicate target to account for the change, then it's still a duplicate. If the change made it so that people who come to the marked-as-duplicate question are left feeling frustrated "what the hell? how is this a duplicate? this duplicate link reads like an unrelated question! it doesn't answer what I wanted to know!", that's a bad marking-as-duplicate, and it's very appropriate to contribute to un-duplicating them.

Comment: Of course a lingering problem on stackoverflow is that the people judging things as duplicates are not always great at it. Deduplication of questions takes some skills without which you can still ask good questions and provide good answers, so it's fairly easy to get your way up to those moderation privileges without actually being reliably good at consciously noticing relevant differences in questions or how a close-as-duplicate would be unhelpful and frustrating to people actually looking for the best answers to appropriate-for-SO questions.

Comment: "the questions were arguably duplicates in the past because at the time they warranted the same answers" this is something that should not happen. Duplicates should be evaluated for the problem being asked about, not about the (potential or posted) answers.

Comment: "the questions were arguably duplicates in the past because at the time they warranted the same answers" this is exactly what should happen. Duplicates should be evaluated for the answer being asked for, not about the literal question. As answers may change over time, so may duplicates representing answers.